How do I load 3rd party library (`citeproc`, in my case) in to Emacs started with a `emacs -Q` and a custom script?
I am trying to publish a HTML webpage using an Org file. I am using a very standard Lisp script that I execute in the terminal as: emacs -Q --script script.el
(require 'ox-publish)

(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(
        ("org-notes"
         :base-directory "./content"
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "./public"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
         :headline-levels 4
         :auto-preamble t
         )
        ("org-static"
         :base-directory "./content"
         :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf\\|txt\\|cur\\|svg\\|csv\\|json"
         :publishing-directory "./public"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
         )
        ("org"
         :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))))

(org-publish "org")

I am using a csl file rather than the basic or bibtex options in my Org file:
#+AUTHOR: Me
#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: ~/bib/references.bib
#+CITE_EXPORT: csl ~/Zotero/styles/apa.csl

When I export directly from Org-mode to a PDF or a HTML there is no error, but when I run my script.el, which is my preferred approach, I get the following error:
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/topcat/projects/notes_org/build-site.el" nil t)
  #f(compiled-function (buffer file) #<bytecode 0x146acef1111a2e2b>)(#<buffer  *load*> "/Users/topcat/projects/notes_org/build-site.el")
  load-with-code-conversion("~/projects/notes_org/build-site.el" "/Users/topcat/projects/notes_org/build-site.el" nil t #f(compiled-function (buffer file) #<bytecode 0x146acef1111a2e2b>))
  command-line--load-script("~/projects/notes_org/build-site.el")
  command-line-1(("-scriptload" "./build-site.el"))
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
Citeproc library is not loaded

I am bit lost and haven't found good documentation regarding references using oc.el in HTML project exports.

Did you try explicitly loading the citeproc library with (require 'citeproc) ?

Yes, but I get an error message because it cannot find 'citeproj despite being installed and printed in my load-path. I am running my script using emacs -Q, no not sure if that affects the load-path.

The -Q switch instructs Emacs to skip loading any init files, so yes, it typically affects the load-path. I'd try adding the directory of citeproc to the load-path in your script.

I made it work using (package-initialize) in the script to load the use-package library.

For libraries that are not include in the Emacs distribution, they need to be called, either as:
(add-to-list 'load-path "<path to citeproj>")
(require 'citeproc)

or just load the use-package using
(package-initialize)

This works for my case, but wondering what to do if you have a different setting.
